# What is the meaning of Dr. Samuel Loomis' words about Michael Myers' behavior?

Tags: plot-explanation, halloween-2007

In *Halloween* (2007), Dr. Samuel Loomis took an observation job over Michael Myers.

> Michael's so-called normal moments are becoming fewer and fewer,and
>   I'm particularly worried about this.I believe that these masks have
>   begun to create a mental sanctuary in which Michael can hide **within
>   himself and from himself**.

What does **within himself and from himself** mean here?